# Forward TCP packets from one connection to another

Tags: beginner, rust, networking

I am new to Rust but well versed in Go. I have written the following program which initiates connection to the `remote-addr` and starting a thread to listen to the incoming connections at `local-addr`. It will forward packets received from the remote connection to all incoming connections. The program works very well but wanted a code review here.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::env;
use std::io::{Error, Write};
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, Sender};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;
use std::{io::Read, net::TcpListener, net::TcpStream};

fn handle_stream(stream: &mut TcpStream, tx: &Sender<Vec<u8>>) -> Result<usize, Error> {
    let mut buf = [0; 1024];

    let n = stream.read(&mut buf[..])?;

    tx.send(buf.to_vec()).unwrap_or_else(|error| {
        panic!("Sending error: {:?}", error.to_string());
    });

    Ok(n)
}

fn process_args(cargs: Vec<String>) -> HashMap<String, String> {
    let mut args = HashMap::new();
    for e in cargs {
        let arg: Vec<&str> = e.as_str().split("=").collect();
        match arg[0] {
            "--remote-addr" => {
                args.insert(String::from("remote-addr"), String::from(arg[1]));
            }
            "--local-addr" => {
                args.insert(String::from("local-addr"), String::from(arg[1]));
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }
    args
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let cargs: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();

    let args = process_args(cargs);
    if *&args.is_empty()
        || *&args.get("remote-addr").is_none()
        || *&args.get("local-addr").is_none()
    {
        panic!("expected args: remote and local addr")
    }

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let i_stream: Arc<Mutex<Vec<Result<TcpStream, Error>>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Vec::new()));
    let mut handles = vec![];

    let i_stream_c1 = Arc::clone(&i_stream);
    let handle = thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let received: Vec<u8> = rx.recv().unwrap();
        let mut streams_to_delete: Vec<usize> = Vec::new();

        let mut incoming_stream = i_stream_c1.lock().unwrap();
        for (idx, s) in incoming_stream.iter().enumerate() {
            let mut x = s.as_ref().unwrap();

            _ = x.write(received.as_slice()).unwrap_or_else(|_| {
                streams_to_delete.push(idx);
                0
            });
        }

        for idx in streams_to_delete.iter() {
            incoming_stream.remove(*idx).unwrap();
        }
    });
    handles.push(handle);

    let i_stream_c2 = Arc::clone(&i_stream);
    let args1 = args.clone();

    let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
        let listener = TcpListener::bind(args1.get("local-addr").unwrap()).unwrap();
        println!(
            "ready to accept connections at {:?}",
            args1.get("local-addr").unwrap()
        );

        for stream in listener.incoming() {
            println!(
                "new connection from {:?}",
                stream.as_ref().unwrap().peer_addr().unwrap()
            );
            let mut incoming_stream = i_stream_c2.lock().unwrap();
            incoming_stream.push(stream);
        }
    });
    handles.push(handle);

    let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(args.get("remote-addr").unwrap())?;
    println!("connecting to {:?}", args.get("remote-addr").unwrap());
    loop {
        let mut break_loop = false;
        handle_stream(&mut stream, &tx).unwrap_or_else(|_| {
            break_loop = true;
            0
        });

        if break_loop {
            break;
        }
    }

    for handle in handles {
        handle.join().unwrap();
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

Here the error control is not so considered, hence you will see lot of `unwrap`s. But that was intentional as it was not PROD ready code.

To run: `./tcp_forwarder --remote-addr=0.0.0.0:2100 --local-addr=0.0.0.0:2100`

Comment: @RichardNeumann I think it's fine to use a small function to parse arguments instead of pulling a large library such as `clap`.

Answer (score 2):

1. I would use [scoped threads](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/thread/fn.scope.html) instead of `thread::spawn()`. This allows you to avoid the `Arc` and cloning `args`.
2. For `args`, I would use a struct instead of a `HashMap`.
3. If you insist on using a map for the args, checking `args.is_empty()` is redundant - if it is empty, `remote-addr` and `local-addr` will be `None`.
4. I would move the check of the args to `process_args()`. This is subjective, but I think validating the arguments is part of processing them.
5. Instead of using `split("=")` and collecting to `Vec` (by the way: prefer `split('=')` to `split("=")` as it is more performant, [there is even a Clippy lint for that](https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/#single_char_pattern)), you can use [`split_once()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_once).
6. You don't need to collect `std::env::args()` to a `Vec`, as you immediately iterate over them.
7. Instead of using a variable `break_loop` because you cannot break from inside the closure, you can just give up on using `unwrap_or_else()` and use a simple `if handle_stream(&mut stream, &tx).is_err() { break; }`. Or even `while handle_stream(&mut stream, &tx).is_ok() {}` (although I dislike that, as I dislike empty loop bodies).
8. This is rather minor, but I would replace:

```rust
let mut incoming_stream = i_stream_c2.lock().unwrap();
incoming_stream.push(stream);
```

With:

```rust
i_stream_c2.lock().unwrap().push(stream);
```

This also means that the `MutexGuard` is a temporary, meaning that we unlock the mutex at the end of the statement and not of the block, so if we add new statements after we won't hold the lock longer than needed.

9. Instead of pushing `Result`s to `i_stream` and `unwrap()`ing them on the first thread, I would `unwrap()` them on the second immediately when we connect to them, needing to do that only once.
10. Instead of using `unwrap_or_else()` after `x.write()`, forcing you to return a dummy result, I would do:

```rust
if x.write(received.as_slice()).is_err() {
    streams_to_delete.push(idx);
}
```

11. If two streams are scheduled for removal, you will remove the wrong stream as the indices will be shuffled after the first stream will be removed. Instead, remove them in a reverse order.
12. I would use `streams_to_delete.into_iter()` instead of `streams_to_delete.iter()`, also saving a dereference. You can replace this with just `streams_to_delete`, but you cannot if you reverse it as per the previous comment.
13. This is a neat one (IMO): instead of storing indices to remove, you can use [`retain_mut()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain_mut):

```rust
i_stream.lock().unwrap().retain_mut(|x| x.write(received.as_slice()).is_ok());
```

14. `panic!("Sending error: {:?}", error.to_string())` -> `panic!("Sending error: {error}")`. Not exactly the same (the previous prints the string in debug representation) but this is probably what you wanted anyway.
15. `&mut buf[..]` -> `&mut buf`, and also `received.as_slice()` -> `&received`, thanks to deref coercion. But this is matter of style; you can prefer your version.
16. You send the whole `buf`, which is filled with zeroes after the message. You need to truncate it: `buf[..n].to_vec()` instead of `buf.to_vec()`.
17. Instead of allocating a `Vec` for each packet, you can send the array. This saves an allocation per packet. You also need to send the size with it, otherwise you won't know how long the packet is (see the previous comment).
18. Your imports are in two flavors: each module get a new `use` and combined for all (the last line). Choose one flavor and stick with it.
19. [`write()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write) is not guaranteed to write all data. Use [`write_all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all) instead. Did you run Clippy and it reported an error "written amount is not handled" so you added the `_ =` ? This is a very bad idea. Don't silence warnings, listen to them (and by the way, run Clippy. I don't do that as an experienced Rustacean because I have my own preferences, but as a beginner it will help you a lot. It reports some warning with your original code, try it yourself).

The code after all changes:

````rust
use std::env;
use std::io::{Error, Read, Write};
use std::net::{TcpListener, TcpStream};
use std::sync::mpsc::{self, Sender};
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::thread;

const PACKET_SIZE: usize = 1024;

fn handle_stream(
    stream: &mut TcpStream,
    tx: &Sender<([u8; PACKET_SIZE], usize)>,
) -> Result<usize, Error> {
    let mut buf = [0; PACKET_SIZE];

    let n = stream.read(&mut buf)?;

    tx.send((buf, n)).unwrap_or_else(|error| {
        panic!("Sending error: {error}");
    });

    Ok(n)
}

#[derive(Default)]
struct Args {
    remote_addr: String,
    local_addr: String,
}

fn process_args(cargs: impl Iterator<Item = String>) -> Args {
    let mut args = Args::default();

    for e in cargs {
        match e.split_once('=') {
            Some(("--remote-addr", value)) => {
                args.remote_addr = String::from(value);
            }
            Some(("--local-addr", value)) => {
                args.local_addr = String::from(value);
            }
            _ => (),
        }
    }

    if args.remote_addr.is_empty() || args.local_addr.is_empty() {
        panic!("expected args: remote and local addr")
    }

    args
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let args = process_args(env::args());

    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
    let i_stream: Mutex<Vec<TcpStream>> = Mutex::new(Vec::new());

    thread::scope(|s| {
        s.spawn(|| {
            let rx = rx; // Force a move for `rx`, otherwise we get an error as it does not implement `Sync`.
            loop {
                let (received, n): ([u8; PACKET_SIZE], usize) = rx.recv().unwrap();
                let received = &received[..n];
                i_stream
                    .lock()
                    .unwrap()
                    .retain_mut(|x| x.write_all(received).is_ok());
            }
        });

        s.spawn(|| {
            let listener = TcpListener::bind(&args.local_addr).unwrap();
            println!("ready to accept connections at {:?}", &args.local_addr);

            for stream in listener.incoming() {
                let stream = stream.unwrap();
                println!("new connection from {:?}", stream.peer_addr().unwrap());
                i_stream.lock().unwrap().push(stream);
            }
        });

        let mut stream = TcpStream::connect(&args.remote_addr)?;
        println!("connecting to {:?}", &args.remote_addr);
        loop {
            if handle_stream(&mut stream, &tx).is_err() {
                break;
            }
        }
        Ok(())
    })
}
```
````

Answer (score 1):

## Use existing libraries

Use e.g. [`clap`](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/) to parse the command line arguments. I recommend its `derive` feature. This way, you only have to define one struct and the parsing magic is done for you by a proven an tested framework.

While it may be okay to manually yank the args from the cargs API in a small project, you'll soon get into the habit of copy-pasting such code snippets into future projects resulting in [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself#WET) code.

## Naming

> There are only two hard things in Computer Science: cache invalidation and naming things.
> -- Phil Karlton

Your function name `handle_stream` does not convey, what it *actually* does.
It forwards one stream to another. So why not call it `forward_stream` instead? Also its parameters are misleading. `sender` is the stream, that gets the data, while `stream` is a stream being read from.
So a better fit for their names might be `src` and `dst` (or, `source` and `destination` if you like to be more verbose).

## `main` should be lean

Your current `main` function is the longest function in your entire program. That is a sign of suboptimal design. `main` should just set up your program and invoke the functions that actually do the business. Consider splitting it up into further functions that are then invoked in `main`.

You will see that by carefully splitting responsibility while adhering to the principles of functional programming, your functions will get more concise and actually (unit-) testable.

## Rethink your design

Your program currently only forwards between TCP sockets. Since you're basically reinventing netcat here, why not take its example and allow reading from STDIN and writing to STDOUT as well. This would hugely simplify your code, since you would no longer need threads to forward between two TCP sockets, but use two separate processes instead:

```
$ ./tcp_forwarder --listen=0.0.0.0:2100 | ./tcp_forwarder --send=0.0.0.0:2100
```

Comment: `forward_stream()` is also not a good name IMO as it does not actually forward anything, just sends to the channel. Maybe `send_packet_to_channel()`? Also, in my opinion in short scripty programs a long `main()` is fine.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your opinion. Given my review, you already know mine.